# No spark either side

Tags: ford, starting, ignition, cranks-wont-run

Engine won't start but turns over.  4 cyl with 8 spark plugs all eight produce no spark while cranking.

I have an 1989 ford ranger xlt 2wd 4 cyl.  During the crazy cold spell here in northern Kentucky it wouldn't start and I attributed it to a bad battery(which was bad).  I have changed the battery and the temperatures have returned to their normal 30 - 40 F range but the truck still won't start.

Things I have checked:

1. I checked to see if the timing was good.  No problems there.
2. Crank sensor/Harmonic balancer. Everything checked out. **assumption was wrong**
3. All not-inline fuses. Both panels in the cab and under the hood.
4. Tested the ignition control module.(bench tested)
5. Fuel system(inertial switch , pump, starting fluid...)

I have not went through and checked all of the inline fuses for continuity.  Does anyone have any leads on what may be causing this and possibly a fix?

Comment: Don't know how cold it got but have you considered a frozen fuel line? Do you have spark?

Comment: @mikes The temperatures came up to about low 40's over the last couple days.  The temperatures were down around -10 F when I had the trouble, but I think it has had time to thaw out.  No spark either side.

Comment: How did you test the control module?

Comment: @mikes ... Check #4 above.

Comment: Not did you, but how did you, there are some testing issues with certain aftermarket modules and specific scanners.

Comment: @mike I took it to Autozone, they have a bench tester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad crank sensor

Well,  it turns out that the 2nd bullet on my list of things not wrong was incorrect.  I had "assumed" that the crank sensor was fine because I had just put a new one in not 3 months ago with a brand new harmonic balancer.  Plus it looked perfect as far as a visual inspection.  No odd wear or corrosion just a little soot built up on the magnets.

Without much else to go on, I pulled the crank sensor and swapped it out for a new one since it was under warranty.  It fired right up yesterday and seems to be running fine.

Comment: I also just found out they have a bench tester for crank sensors at autozone.  Wouldn't have thought they would.